# Is a Linux live CD safe? Password is known

Tags: linux

For the Mint Linux live CD the login is "mint" and the password is blank (there is no password, when asked, simply press Enter). It appears that the live CD is in root or superuser mode by default.

For over a decade I have been using TENS Linux for banking. They closed. I am looking for a trustworthy replacement.

I guess I can unhook my internet cable before turning on my computer. Change the default password and then connect my internet cable, but I would not like this option.

A long time ago, I booted with a live CD and enabled SSH. I was able to log into my computer from another computer in the room because I knew the default password.

Comment: What exactly is your question? "Security" is not unidirectional - you can only be safe *from* specific threats. So, what are your threats?

Comment: *"A long time ago, I booted with a live CD and enabled SSH."* - this is basically saying that you explicitly opened up your computer for external access, overriding the more secure default settings. This has not much to do with the weak password - of course you need to harden your password (or better: don't use passwords but keys) when opening up your system for remote access.

Comment: And you can't change the password on a running system? What's your concern?

Answer (score 4):

A Live-CD (especially when it is really a CD or DVD) always provide the same environment after start, which may or may not be secure. Reasons for insecurity may, for example, be outdated browser versions.

Without enabling remote access (ssh et al.) or leaving the room (so someone can use your computer with the default password), there is little risk from having a standard password as nobody will be able to use it.

Some Live-CDs also allow to set passwords after booting.

Answer (score 0):

Having a default password is bad.  Regularly using a machine with a known password is inadvisable.  There was a notable raspberry pi botnet at one point for exactly this reason.

However, it could be "safe" depending on one's threat profile and mitigations.

The dance of unplugging the network before changing passwords, while fun, is likely unnecessary for the average user.  However, I might suggest instead learning how to modify a Live CD to not have a default password.